# What is the proper XPath for "all nodes exactly one below the base node?"

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Presuming that I don't know the name of my base node or its children, what is the XPath syntax for "all nodes exactly one below the base node?"

With pattern being an XmlNode, I have the following code:

```
XmlNodeList kvpsList = pattern.SelectNodes(@"//");
```

Which looks right to me, but I get the following exception:

```
   System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Note for later readers: by "base node", Jekke apparently means the top-level element (also known as the "document element", or "outermost element"). Jekke's usage is confusing because he does *not* mean the root node (/), which is the parent of the top-level element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The two current answers are wrong:**

```
/*/*
```

**does not select all nodes that are children of the top node**. It does not select any text nodes, processing-instructions or comments that are children of the top element.

**One XPath expression that select all nodes that arte children of the top element is:**

**`/*/node()`**

`//` is not a syntactically correct XPath expression; according to the [XPath Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#path-abbrev):

> // is short for
>   /descendant-or-self::node()/

**Do note** the beginning of an unfinished location step at the very end of the expanded abbreviation. If nothing is added to it, the whole XPath expression containing the abbreviation is finished and, therefore, syntactically incorrect.

**Another note** is that the `//` abbreviation is not necessary in specifying the selection of all nodes that are children of the top element. If you wanted to select all nodes in the XML document that **descend** from the top element, then one XPath expression that select these is:

**`/*//node()`**

Answer (score 8):

The path you're looking for is

```
/*/*
```

`//` isn't a meaningful XPath expression, since it is an operator. If you wrote something like `//element`, it would match every element named `element` anywhere in the XML document, no matter how deep into the hierarchy it is.

`/*/*` is saying "match every node that has two levels of depth in the hierarchy".

Comment: both this answer and @Jweede's confuse the terms "node" and "element". I suspect @Jekke also confused the terms, so these answers are correct with regard to what he meant, but not with regard to what he said. "Nodes" include elements, attributes, text nodes, root nodes, and others. Elements are the things expressed with start/end tags: `<foo> </foo>`. The XPath "*" with no axis specified matches only *elements*. See @Dimitre's answer for more on that.